# A network-related or instance-specific error when trying to get the user Role?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I'm doing a simple check if user is in role Administrator to show an item in the Navigation:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit categories", "Index", "Category", new { area = "Administration" }, null)</li>
}
```

... and I got this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Any workaround?

EDIT: My connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings> <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ForumDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\ForumDB.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> </connectionStrings>
```

P.S. using .Net Framework 4.5 / Entity Framework 5 / VS 2013 RC / LocalDb / Asp.Net MVC 4

Comment: Please check your `connectionstring and user name and pwd`. It should be `connectivity issue`

Comment: Looks like your connection string is pointing to a SQL server instance which does not exists.

Comment: I'm using LocalDb. My connection string is:
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ForumDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\ForumDB.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Can you add the connection string to your post so others can see it easier?